# How to load my vscode extension as the first extension in the activity bar

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm building a vscode extension that has a webview view panel and I want to render that extension icon just above the file explorer by default in the activity bar and it should get open by defaut when someone open vscode.

Anyone can help here!

Ps:I tried adding `order: 0` in package.json file but it didn't work for me.

Comment: what does the VSC doc tell you about the placement of activity bar icons? Most likely they do not allow because it would mean that everybody wants to be on top

Comment: Your extension can only define a icon there, and the actual order is determined by the end users who can drag and drop.

Comment: where did you get this "order" thing from?